# C# Object Creation Performance Metrics

Tags: c#, performance, garbage-collection, metrics

I'm looking for good performance metrics around the cost of creating objects in C#. I am trying to decide if it's best to "denormaise" a number of classes into a single upper-level class in an effort to avoid costly garbage collection efforts. There is an obvious trade-off here in that I will lose a level of readability in-so-far as data that would have previously have been stored in it's own class would be re-factored up to a higher-level class.

To add some context - I am dealing with the creation of roughly 500 extra classes per call. Calls will be relatively infrequent.

Comment: Did you profile the application to determine whether this is even a problem? I always learn toward readability and maintainability unless it's an obvious issue of performance.

Comment: MY general philosophy is to always design for readability, maintainability and that it just plain works. If you have performance issues then optimise for performance.  Never optimise for performance issues that may never exist.

Answer (score 2):

If you're handling large collections of the similar classes then maybe you should look at the use of generic classes.